# DAX expression to extract value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to write a dax expression that allows me to extract the contents of column B based on column A.

Column A being a filter in my report.

Regards,

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ab | 1 |
| ac | 2 |
| ad | 3 |

In this logic : if A = ab then 1 as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this measure

```
B (ab) = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Table'[B]),
    'Table'[A] = "ab"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't this solve your problem? Why not?